# How to populate a table with a value from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

When populating a column from another table's column with conditions

```
UPDATE EVENT E 
SET TIMESTART = (SELECT TIMESTART FROM EVENTSTEPS WHERE STEPNUMBER=1) 
WHERE EVENTREF = (SELECT EVENTREF FROM EVENTSTEPS);
```

I am getting this error in 10g:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

I don't know what's the right thing to do if I want to  populate a table's column from other tables column. Can someone help me out on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO EVENT e
  USING (SELECT EVENTREF, TIMESTART
           FROM EVENTSTEPS
           WHERE STEPNUMBER = 1) s
  ON (s.EVENTREF = e.EVENTREF)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
    SET e.TIMESTART = s.TIMESTART;
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

The update statement requires we assign one value to the the column in the SET clause. Your sub-query returns a row for *every* EVENTSTEPS record where STEPNUMBER = 1. This is because you are not restricting the sub-query to return only the row for the current EVENT.

What you need is a correlated sub-query:

```
UPDATE EVENT E 
SET e.TIMESTART = (SELECT es.TIMESTART 
                   FROM EVENTSTEPS es
                   WHERE es.EVENTREF = e.EVENTREF
                   and es.STEPNUMBER=1) 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning or updating any value from subquery then it should return only one value so then it can get update.

```
UPDATE EVENT E SET TIMESTART = (SELECT max(TIMESTART) FROM EVENTSTEPS WHERE STEPNUMBER=1) 
WHERE EVENTREF = (SELECT max(EVENTREF) FROM EVENTSTEPS);
```

And in where condition that subquery returns more than one row and you want to update for all the rows which met the condition then put `in` instead of `=`